# Why am I getting grainy images when converting a graph generated with ggplot2 to pdf passing from PowerPoint?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2, powerpoint

I produced a series of graphs using ggplot2 R package. I imported some of these plots in PowerPoint, and now I would like to convert them into a unique PDF. When I import (i.e. copy and paste) a graph on PowerPoint the resolution is perfectly kept, but when I try to export from ppt to pdf just some of these graph (which I saved using the same parameters of all the other plots) are pretty grainy. So far, I tried to save the plots in several formats (pdf, jpeg, tiff) with both `pdf()` and `ggsave()`, but I keep having the same issue.
Did anybody have the same issue?

Comment: have you tried turning off picture compression in PowerPoint? https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/turn-off-picture-compression-81a6b603-0266-4451-b08e-fc1bf58da658 Perhaps having the original graph in "too high" resolution is what pushed PowerPoint to compress them more. If it's really only at the export to pdf stage, then it probably depends on what you use to export to pdf (and if you can enable lossless compression there)

Comment: Try saving the plots in svg format.

Comment: Vector formats are less likely to become pixelated. The vector format with the best support in Office is EMF. You can export very good EMFs using the free program InkScape. https://inkscape.org/ InkScape is also scriptable, in case you are setting up a scripted workflow.

Comment: The solution proposed by @giocomai is the one works perfectly. Thank you all!